# How to Add elements into ArrayList in non-continuous indexes and show them

Tags: java, arraylist

My friends, I need some help. It's may easy to solve but I do not can. My code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> geno = new ArrayList<Integer>();
geno.set(2, 0);
geno.set(3, 0);
geno.set(4, 0);
geno.set(5, 0);

geno.forEach(???????);
```

How to implement a loop that displays the indices and their values?

I need show this:

{2 -> 0; 3 -> 0; 4 -> 0; 5 -> 0}

Answer (score -1):

You're output is not printing indices, you're output is asking for something like this

`geno.forEach(item=>console.log(item[0], '->', item[1])`

If you want indices printed then something like this should do it,

`geno.forEach((item,index)=>console.log(index, '->', item[1])`

you would get this,

`{0 -> 0; 1 -> 0; 2 -> 0; 3 -> 0}`

Comment: The code in the question is Java, not JavaScript. Java is not JavaScript.